# Trying to count amount of occurences after a certain word from certain JSON file but am having trouble

Tags: python, json

ERROR     numCraft = data['craft']

KeyError: 'craft'

I have tried to implement different counts and loops but am having trouble just count the amount of different crafts. The answer is two but just do not know how to implement or understand the concept of JSON

Comment: If you're getting an error, post it.  Putting "#Error" in the code doesn't tell us much.

Comment: That json content does not contain `craft` as a top-level item.  Instead, `craft` is a sub-component of each item in the `people` list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a (shortened) version of the json content from that url:

```
{
  "message": "success",
  "people": [
    {
      "name": "Cai Xuzhe",
      "craft": "Tiangong"
    },
    {
      "name": "Chen Dong",
      "craft": "Tiangong"
    },
    {
      "name": "Anna Kikina",
      "craft": "ISS"
    }
  ],
  "number": 10
}
```

As you can see, the top-level items are `message`, `people`, and `number`.  There is no top-level item named `craft`.

So that is why you got that error.

You probably wanted something like this:

```
all_crafts = set()
for person in data['people']:
    name = person['name']
    craft = person['craft']
    print(f'The astronaut {name} was in the craft {craft}')
    all_crafts.add(craft)

print('There were this many different crafts:', len(all_crafts))
```

Comment: Ah okay, Thank you! Is there a way to count the number of instances of different crafts

Comment: Yes.  Add each craft name to a set as you're iterating over the people, and then print the length of that set at the end.  See my edited answer.

Comment: That makes much more sense. I appreciate your assistance! I had trouble understanding sub lists.